# Concordancia de pronombres en "me amenazó con hacerme daño a mí y a mi familia"

Tags: gramática, concordancia-gramatical

Desde una serie de Netflix "La Víctima Número Ocho" (España) vi lo siguiente:

*...si yo estuviera en tu lugar, diría que **me** amenazó con hacer**me** daño **a mí** y **a mi** familia si no colaboraba.*

Pregunta: Por qué no se usó el pronombre "*nos*" ("*con hacer**nos** daño*")? Sugiero que esto es solo el cuestión de subrayar. "*Con hacer**nos** daño*" sería también correcto, pero al usar "*con hacer**me** daño*" significaría que unas consecuencias le podrían emocionalmente afectar más a esta persona.

P.S. Por adelantado les agradezco a todos ustedes los que corrijan errores en mi letra si haya algunos, o en gramática o en uso de palabras o en algo más.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La oración:

- Me amenazó con hacer**nos** daño a mí y a mi familia si no colaboraba.

es en efecto más correcta que:

- Me amenazó con hacer**me** daño a mí y a mi familia si no colaboraba.

La segunda oración sería la versión en lenguaje indirecto de una amenaza hecha en forma oral, donde suele ocurrir que se hace referencia al objeto más próximo. Podría interpretarse como:

- Me amenazó con hacer**me** daño a mí y (también con hacerle daño) a mi familia si no colaboraba.